# Using regex within a case statement to pull out dynamic content

Tags: regex, case, amazon-redshift

I am working with URL strings that have the following structure:

```
URL 
page/wa/seattle
page/ca/sandiego
page/mi/detroit
```

I essentially was wondering if it is possible to use Regex in combination with a case statement to create the following:

```
Page        State      City 
page        wa         seattle
page        ca         sandiego
page        mi         detroit
```

I currently have the code written that pulls out which pages are state pages and which pages are city pages.

```
CASE WHEN (regexp_instr(HITSPAGEPAGEPATH::text, '^/page/[a-z]{2}/[a-z]+':: 
           CHARACTER VARYING::text)) 
     THEN (regexp_instr(HITSPAGEPAGEPATH::text, 
           '^/page/[a-z]{2}/[a-z]+'::CHARACTER VARYING::text)) 
     ELSE NULL 
END AS city
```

The part that I can't figure out is what I can put after the "then' to have just the city or state displayed. This is for postgres sql on Amazon redshift using sql workbench if that helps with what syntax to answer in.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a regex, just split the string in 3 elements (separated by `/`)  and use each element as a column:

```
select elements[1] as page, 
       elements[2] as state,
       elements[3] as city
from (
   select string_to_array(hitspagepagepath, '/') as elements
   from the_table
) t
order by page;
```

Comment: I get an error that says "column "elements" does not exist in t

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that regex isn't needed but would what I am proposing  even be possible?

Comment: @camacnei: sorry, forgot the column alias.

Comment: oops getting a different error now. "string_to_array" is not supported by Redshift :(

Comment: Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Thanks for the methodology idea.  In redshift the command to use is split_part instead of string to array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select hitspagepagepath, split_part(hitspagepagepath,'/',2) as root_url,
                     split_part(hitspagepagepath,'/',3) as State,
                     split_part(hitspagepagepath,'/',4) as City
    from Table
```